# What is the criteria to get qualified for Trophy in Review Board?

Tags: review-board

Trophies are achievements that can be awarded to users based on some aspect of a review request. I want to know what are those aspects.

Answer (score 7):

Please see [this](http://www.cryan.com/daily/20140909.jsp) blog post for an explanation:

- Generally big, round, numbers (1000, 2000, etc.) sometimes known as Odometer numbers.
- Palindromes (e.g 416614) trigger the Fish Trophy as well.